# Need a Windows 10 video driver for a ThinkPad R60

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, thinkpad

A search at Leno's website does not find a Windows 10 or Windows 7 video driver for a ThinkPad R60, type 9459-AT8. Where can I find a video driver for this older machine?

Comment: What do you see when booting Windows 10? No display at all? Low-res graphics?

Comment: 1024x768 hicolor but Windows kvetches that it wants a better driver.

Comment: If that's the max resolution of the LCD display, and you're not using  a separate monitor, just stop driver updates: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-driver-updates/63957b76-b55c-4c59-93f0-72835e9b2fff BTW, it's *possible*, if not likely, another OS has newer drivers... test Linux from USB (no need to install) to see if the display is better, or, for that matter if it runs faster.

Comment: Oh, Mint is faster but the recipient is Windows-centric and has no local support

Answer (score 2):

Your computer dates from about 2006. You won't find a Win10 driver for such an old machine. Last will probably be for Win7. Basically, even though Microsoft allowed computers made before 2015 to run Win 10, a lot of GPU manufacturers used it as an excuse to drop support for older models. Yours is actually old enough it was probably dropped even before that, likely as Win 8 was released.

The simplest way to figure out exactly what you need is to use the [Intel® Driver & Support Assistant (Intel® DSA)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html)